# Data not received in c server while using executor service from a java client

Tags: java, c, client-server, executorservice

i have a simple c server and java client implementation and i am testing the server for request handling. I am using executor service for simulating simultaneous requests.

Mechanism : The sever just reads a string from client and acknowledges it by sending back a message to the client.

Issue : For some requests the server doesn't get the message which was sent by the client.

C server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    //strlen
#include <stdlib.h>    //strlen
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include <unistd.h>    //write
#include <pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread

//the thread function
void *connection_handler(void *);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    static int client_count = 0;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 5000 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 1000);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    pthread_t thread_id;

    while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        client_count++;
        printf("Connection accepted for client no : %d\n",client_count);

        if( pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) &client_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        //pthread_join( thread_id , NULL);
        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
    }

    void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
    {
        //Get the socket descriptor
        int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
        int read_size, t = 0, operation = -1, buffer_size = 0;
        char *message , recv_meta[2000], *data[3];

        //Receive a message from client
        while(read_size = recv(sock, recv_meta, 2000, 0) > 0 ) {
        printf("Meta from client : %s\n",recv_meta);
        sprintf(recv_meta, "%s", "OK, Meta Data received!");
       send(sock, recv_meta, strlen(recv_meta), 0); //send acknowledgement
    }
    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    return 0;
   }
```

Java Client:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class client
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ExecutorService executorService =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
             Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(""+i);
            executorService.execute(worker);
        }
        executorService.shutdown();        
    }
}

class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
    String clientcount = "";
    public WorkerThread(String s){
        this. clientcount=s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        int PORT = 5000, buffer_size = 0;
        String meta = " ";

        meta = "newfileidforenc:1:20000";

       // Create the socket connection to the EchoServer.
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
        }        
        catch(UnknownHostException uhe)
        {
            // Host unreachable
            System.out.println("Unknown Host");
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            // Cannot connect to port on given host
            System.out.println("Cant connect to server at port "+PORT+". Make sure it is running.");
            return;
        }
        try
        {
        PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader pin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        pout.println(meta);
        pout.flush();
        System.out.println("\nServer Says : " + pin.readLine() + "for "+ clientcount);
        }
        catch(Exception ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("\nException during communication. Server probably closed connection.");
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                // Close the socket before quitting
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Output : It is not the same. All the client gets connected and disconnect successfully. But the server doesn't receive and print the data from all the clients.

Comment: Well, straight off, server ignores the 'read_size' return from the recv() call after a successful read.  Then 'printf("Meta from client : %s\n",recv_meta);' tries to printf a buffer that is not guaranteed null-terminated.

Comment: Even if the recv() call reads the whole line sent from the client in one go, (which is NOT guaranteed), client sends data that is not null-terminated.

Comment: 'pthread_create( ....,&client_sock'), passes the address of a var that is local to the accept() thread instead of passing it by value.

Comment: Even though the string sent by the client isn't null terminated, the read_size will be greater than zero so it should go inside the while() condition right?

Comment: Yes, it should, assuming that 'sock' is correct, which it may not be because of the 'passing socket by address' issue.

Comment: 'strlen(recv_meta)' will not work.  Check ALL C functions that expect null-terminated strings.  It's usual to use the 'read_size' value to add a null to the end of the received data.  Note that this means that the buffer needs to be one byte longer than the size of data requested in the recv() call, (to leave space for the null if the recv call returns all the data requsted).

Comment: Can you give a lil more explanation on why passing socket by its address is an issue here?

Comment: It's bad because every client<>server thread will be reading from the same location in the accept thread and so will be reading from the same client_sock - the last one to be accepted.

Comment: It gives me a segmentation fault if i pass it value.

Comment: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#CreatingThreads pls check this here, they have mentioned that arg must be passed as a reference.

Comment: 'It gives me a segmentation fault if i pass it value' - you are doing it wrong.

Comment: 'arg must be passed as a reference' - I don't need to open that tutorial.  It's either completely wrong or misleading.  If you want to pass something into pthread_create() by reference/pointer, it must be something whose ownership can be transferred to the new thread, not something that belongs to the creating thread and so may be overwritten and/or destroyed before the new thread gets to use it.

Comment: OK, I opened the tutorial.  You seem to have missed 'Example 3 - Thread Argument Passing (Incorrect)' - this is what you are doing, and it will not work.

Comment: yeah correct, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the issue.

Actual issue : Executor service is used for load testing i.e., there would be more number of requests sent per second. Under such heavy load the code enters a race condition. The client_sock whose address is passed to the pthread_create() is being overwritten by the next accept() call before it is copied to the sock variable inside the connection_handler(). This leads to a scenario where a single connection would be processed by two or more threads and some other connections are left unhandled.

Solution : Copy the client_sock to a string buffer which should be passed as the argument for pthread_create().

Hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have numerous problems with:

1) Not correctly handling TCP streams and assuming that TCP transfers messages instead of octet, (byte) streams.

2) Not appreciating the C-style null-terminated char arrays that msaquerade as a string type.

3) Passing values by address to thread create calls.

See comments.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found a solution for the issue.